# Setup SSH keys but server still prompts for password?

Tags: hadoop, ssh, hadoop2

```
ssh localhost
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa 
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

i followed all above steps in my teminal for disable the password to start the hadoop services ($start-all.sh) but it is still asking for password please anyone  help me to disable password..

Comment: wait, any link of your reference? since `ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa` should be done in master and `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` should be done in slaves. not to mention, how do you intend setup your hadoop? single cluster? multi? standalone? what? sorry for the flags, this one better go into SeverFaults.

Comment: Im trying in pseudo mode

Comment: ah right, also make sure that the `.ssh` directory and the files (both `.pub` and `authorized_keys`) are readable by the hadoop instance. try to assign them `777` since this is on local right?

Answer (score 0):

I had a world of problems with permissions and the .ssh directory.
I think the permissions had to be 600 too but I can't remember exactly.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below link to setup password less ssh it has a best example to get more clarity on ssh setup

https://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/

**Hope this Helps!!!..**

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a multi-node setup, all the nodes must be able to communicate with one another without password. On each node, you generate SSH keys. For example using this command :

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C someemail@.example.com
```

Then you replicate the keys to all the nodes :

```
ssh-copy-id hadoop@master
ssh-copy-id hadoop@slave-01
ssh-copy-id hadoop@slave-02
etc.
```

This needs to be done on each node (every node should have all the keys).

Hope this help !

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.

1. Use ssh-keygen on local server to generate public and private keys.

`$ssh-keygen`Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:

the `ssh-copy-id` copies public key to the remote host

2. `ssh-copy-id` copies public key to remote host

Use `ssh-copy-id`, to copy the public key to the remote host

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 192.168.200.10
```

3. Perform rsync/SCP over ssh without password**
   Now, you should be able to ssh to the remote host without entering the password.

   ```
   ssh 192.168.200.10
   ```

Perform the `rsync` again, it should not ask you to enter any password this time

```
rsync -avz -e ssh /home/Sangita/ sangita@192.168.200.10:/backup/Sangita/
or 
scp /home/Sangita/ sangita@192.168.200.10:/backup/Sangita
```